# Select next element

Tags: jquery

I have following code:

```
<div class="select"><input onclick="return next();" type="radio"></div>
<div class="select" style="display: none" ><input onclick="return next();" type="radio"></div>
<div class="select" style="display: none" ><input onclick="return next();" type="radio"></div>
<script>
function next() {
   $('.select').next().show();
}
</script>
```

Considering I click the first element's radio button. How can I select the next parent element in line. Right now they all show.

Thanks,

Comment: you can use simple html `data` attributes to assign keys and the fetch the `value` of div clicked, then use it to find the `next` div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using jQuery in the wrong way.

All of the elements has the `select` class, you have to make it known to the jQuery code that which `.select` next to which `.select` you want to show, right now clicking on any `.select` element triggers the function that shows the next sibling of all of the `.select` elements.

Instead of using `onclick` attribute to facilitate the click handler

```
<script>
function next() {
   $('.select').next().show();
}
</script>
```

Use jQuery's event attaching

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.select').on("click", function(){
       $(this).next().show();
   });
});
</script>
```

And remove `onclick` attribute from the elements

```
<div class="select"><input  type="radio"></div>
<div class="select" style="display: none" ><input  type="radio"></div>
<div class="select" style="display: none" ><input type="radio"></div>
```

Also note that currently you are looking for clicks on the `.select` element that contains the `radio` input, it opens up possibility that the user may not even check the `radio` input and still the next `.select` element be shown. That is because the div spans more than the area of the `input` element. My suggestion is that either limit the width of the `.select` `div` element to the width of the inner content i.e the input or attach `onchange` event to the `radio` input itself.